# Op-amp with input resistance bigger than output resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework

I am trying to solve this problem, and even though the calculations are fairly simple I am getting a very strange result. I have compared what I get with what my classmates get and what Mathematica yields after solving the equations with no approximations, and I can't make sense of it. The circuit I'm talking about looks like this (I am trying to learn about op-amps):

[image]

The only information given by the textbook is that the differential gain \$A\$ of the op-amp is big but finite, the load resistance in the circuit \$R_L\$ is higher than the output resistance of the op-amp \$R_o\$, and the input resistance of the op-ampt \$R_i\$ is finite. And I need to compute the value of the input resistance, given these facts and the obvious implication that this needs to be modelled as a voltage-dependent controlled source. Therefore I have modelled the op-amp as both terminals being connected by a resistance \$R_i\$ (**which I forgot to label in the next figure, sorry!**) and the output voltage being delivered by a voltage-controlled voltage-source that scales the voltage difference between both terminals by a factor \$A\$. This VCVS is connected to the aforementioned output resistance \$R_o\$:

[image]

From this, I have written the node equation corresponding to the node at the right vertex of the op-amp:

$$\frac{v_{in}-v_{out}}{R_i} + \frac{A(v_{in} - v_{out})-v_{out}}{R_o} = \frac{v_{out}}{R_L}$$

This can be solved taking into account the suppositions given by the problem statement. The result I get is \$Ri = -R_o / A\$, which is clearly nonsensical. For one, the resistance turns out negative. If I plug the same equation in Mathematica, I get a result which is more complicated (due to no approximations being applied) but ultimately simplifies to this, negative sign included. My classmate obtained a result which was very similar, yielding the same negative sign. What am I not understanding? Surely this can't be very complicated, but I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: The internal resistance of the op-amp between the two terminals, which I have called R_i, and which is usually very big in real op-amps.

Comment: The input resistance is normally specified in the datasheet.

Comment: I think you will find that the unmarked resistor (should be marked Ri) does not exist. There should be two separate input resistors from the + and - inputs to ground. Internally the two inputs are not usually connected via any significant resistance. Also worth noting that, normally, Ro << Rl. In other words it's very close to being a voltage source.

Comment: It seems to me that your task is to find the input resistance. Not Ri.  \$R_{in} = \frac{V_{IN}}{I_{IN}}\$

Answer (score 0):

I remaked the circuit and found the "input" impedance of this circuit.

This was made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110) and by Maple sheet.

[image]